# Redirecting Output of a process to a String?

Tags: java, process, output, processbuilder

i'm trying to get the Output of a process to a String, but i'm having some problems. Somehow i managed it to get the Output saved in a separate file (found something here on stackoverflow.com). Here is my Code to get the process to start:

```
    String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");

    String javaBin = javaHome + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator
            + "java";

    String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");

    String className = klasse.getCanonicalName();
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(javaBin, "-cp", classpath,
            className, ip, port, team, "okay");
```

The writing in a file is:

```
     File log = new File("logfile_deleteable" + a);
     builder.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));

     assert builder.redirectInput() == Redirect.PIPE;
     assert builder.redirectOutput().file() == log;
     assert process[a].getInputStream().read() == -1;
```

And at last:

```
    process[a] = builder.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process[a].getInputStream()));
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
   stringBuilder.append(line);
   stringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
String output = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: Somehow my program always freezes when i try this.

Comment: where are you adding this code, after starting the process right?

Comment: I tried adding it before starting the process and after starting the process. Both are leading to freezes.

Comment: how long does the process take to complete without this code?

Comment: can you give a little more detail about the process you are running. You can move the above code in a separate thread, if you do that when are you going to access the string?

Comment: The process is actually a Thread which gives outputs all the time.